# How to get Canon Pixma MX490 to work?

Tags: canon, scanner

Running Xubuntu 14.04. Trying to install Canon MX490 scanner. The printer portion of the MX490 works fine, but the scanner is not recognized. Installed ScangearMP. Also tried SANE. I can print to the printer portion wirelessly and through USB. But the scanner is completely unrecognized.

Comment: Please try this solution: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/12/12/how-to-install-canon-mx490-mx492-mx494-mx495-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-10-wily-32-64bit-quickstart-scanning-easy-guide/ I can't test it since I don't own one, but a friend has tried and told me it works for him, so I hope it works for you too.

Comment: That link has no information about getting the scanner to work. It's all about printing, which the OP says works already.